# Using two IF THEN in sql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, if-statement, syntax-error, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL Workbench. 
I need to check if a certain flag is equal to 1. If the flag is equal to 1, then search by `FollowupDate` else use `QuoteDate`

```
IF(qFollowup = 1) THEN
      IF(pFromFollowupDate != '') THEN
      BEGIN
        SET @Main = CONCAT(@Main, '  AND DATE(q.FollowupDate)  >= \'',pFromFollowupDate,'\' ');
      END;
ELSE
IF(pFromDate != '') THEN
BEGIN
  SET @Main = CONCAT(@Main, '  AND DATE(q.QuoteDate)  >= \'',pFromDate,'\' ');
END;
END IF;
END IF;
```

When I try to apply the changes it says there are syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please show us the error?

Comment: @sagi the error is just a MySQL Workbench pop up saying the object's DDL statement contains syntax errors.

Comment: @RyanVincent do I not need the `;` after each END?

Comment: @RyanVincent removing any of the semicolons causes an error - expected semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_name`()
BEGIN
  IF qFollowup = 1 THEN
    IF pFromFollowupDate != '' THEN
      SET @Main = CONCAT(@Main, '  AND DATE(q.FollowupDate)  >= \'',pFromFollowupDate,'\' ');
    ELSE
      IF pFromDate != '' THEN
        SET @Main = CONCAT(@Main, '  AND DATE(q.QuoteDate)  >= \'',pFromDate,'\' ');
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```